# 2 or more if statements in Excel without using VBA

Tags: excel, logic

Hi I am working with Excel for 1 month and I have a question: is it possible for me to combine 2 if statements? And the cell is from another sheet.
E.g

```
=IF(C2=”Yes”,1,2) + =IF(C2=”Yes”,1,2)
```

is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert your own A1, B1, C1 value

`IF('Sheet1'!A1 = value, true, IF('Sheet1'!B1 = '1 aug dem post'!C1, true, false))`

Comment: i will try to do